# Parsing HTML passed in from JavaScript routine - in IE it comes back with Html tags capitalised - need work around!

Tags: javascript, regex

Ultimately my application is pattern matching based on a text selection within a web browser, generating regEx code so that a portion of a page can be revisited and read anagrammatically.

I'm currently pulling a portion of the text by walking up the dom and then returning innerHtml.

The issue that I have is the text value of the innerHtml property is not consistent, and not properly representative of the literal text.

Tags are capitalised, quotes removed etc, and it varies between browsers.

Is there a way to deal with this client side. I can already read in the literal page text using HttpRequest, but matching using the whole page may be less accurate.

Is this a common issue in JavaScript and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` is indeed bad practice. Apparently it is something introduced by Microsoft in IE that got popular. The thing is, HTML is a DOM; it is not a string. Because `innerHTML` is not a standard, there is not standard way for converting the DOM into a string, and therefore you will get inconsistent results.

The HTML DOM is very extensive - you can do everything you might want to do with `innerHTML` with standardized DOM instead. If you really need to get the text value of a node, the use the property `nodeValue` of that node.

Most of what I am saying came from an article that is a little outdated but still accurate, about [`innerHTML` alternatives](http://slayeroffice.com/articles/innerHTML_alternatives/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. How can I achieve what I need to do here then. After all, what I really want is the raw html text inside an element, not a propriety version translated though the dom. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify - that's raw html text, angle brackets and all

Comment: Sorry for late response, if anyone is still listening!
There is no standard or easy way to do such a thing. Really, why would you need to get raw HTML with angle brackets and everything? Because that is just a string, then you would have to do some regex parsing to convert it into something you can use. Instead of using regex, why not use the DOM itself to get what you need?